# Extract particular text from String in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I m new to snowflake.

**Input String** : ["http://info.wealthenhancement.com/ppc-rt-retirement-planning"]

**Output String** : info.wealthenhancement.com/ppc-rt-retirement-planning

Please help to get output string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [substr](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/substr.html) function to only take characters from the 8th character to the end:

```sql
select 
    'http://info.wealthenhancement.com/ppc-rt-retirement-planning' as orig_value,
    substr(orig_value, 8) as new_value
```

The output is:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|ORIG_VALUE                                                   | NEW_VALUE                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|http://info.wealthenhancement.com/ppc-rt-retirement-planning | info.wealthenhancement.com/ppc-rt-retirement-planning |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Original String is = '["http://info.wealthenhancement.com/ppc-rt-retirement-planning"] '

Comment: Answer from Greg is the way to go in that case

Answer (score 1):

This will work for http and https URLs by splitting using // as a delimiter. Only the last statement is required. The other two show how it's done built into steps:

```
-- Set a session variable to the string
set INPUT_STRING = '["http://info.wealthenhancement.com/ppc-rt-retirement-planning"]';

-- Trim leading and trailing square brackets and double quotes
select (trim($INPUT_STRING, '"[]'));

-- Split using // as a delimiter and keep only the right part and cast as string
select split((trim($INPUT_STRING, '"[]')), '//')[1]::string as URL
```

Comment: Wow!! that's work like charm ..Thanks a lot

Comment: @at9063 be sure to mark this as the answer if it solved your issue